# buying a new unused car parked in storage

Tags: maintenance, used, purchasing

I am thinking of buying a car that has been in storage for the last 9 months.It only clocked less than 30km mileage to date. 
The company that owns this car bought in volume (good discount) for their staff and this particular car was assigned to someone but the person did not use it and just kept the car in storage. The car still has manufacturer warranty for the next 3 years.

What are the keys thing I should look at prior and after taking delivery of the car? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Most newer cars can be left standing for about a year before they need any sort of maintenance upon returning to the road, A few things worth checking would probably be:

1. Battery (it'll probably be flat so charge it up and make sure it holds the charge)
2. Tyres, if the Tyres have gone flat the rim of the wheel will have been sitting on the sidewall of the tyre and could potentially cause a bulge when inflated.
3. Oil, some people say its important to change the oil after a cars been left standing, some don't, it might be worth inspecting it and deciding for yourself.
4. Petrol, Petrol can go "off" so it might be worth googling how to tell if petrol has spoilt and if so drain the tank and fill it with fresh fuel.
5. unwanted pets, depending on where the car has been stored (barn, storage, etc) some unwanted pets may of set up camp in your car, check for any signs of mice or rats trying to eat through the wiring/seating/etc
6. Damp, sometimes cars can suffer from damp if there stored in somewhere that's damp, check for any signs of rust on the bodywork and underneath the car, also check the seals of the doors and boot as mold in the seals is a good sign that damp could of got into the car and affected the interior

That's all i can think of for now but there's probably loads more things to check